# Google App Script: How To Copy format along with name ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am working on app script and currently I want to copy the Ranges data from sheet to doc. I have implemented this successfully. But how can get also the format of table also(ranges). 
Following is my attempt

```
function getDataFromSheet(rangeName,ranges,sheetUrl){  
  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetUrl); 
  var currentSheetId=workbook.getId(); 

  // get the Spreadsheet by sheet id
  var totalSheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(currentSheetId).getSheets();
  for(var i=0; i< totalSheets.length; i++){

    var sheetName = totalSheets[i].getName();
    var sheetNameRanges = SpreadsheetApp.openById(currentSheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);    
    //skip the hidden fields
    if(!sheetNameRanges.isSheetHidden()){     
      var nameRanges = sheetNameRanges.getNamedRanges();
      if(nameRanges.length > 0){
        for(var j=0; j< nameRanges.length; j++){
          //match the name ranges    
          if(nameRanges[j].getName()==rangeName)  {          
            // get the values on selectd range
            var srcData = sheetNameRanges.getRange(ranges).getValues();          
            var range = sheetNameRanges.getRange(ranges);          
            // select this google doc
            var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
            // select the body
            var body = doc.getBody(); 
            table = body.appendTable(srcData);
            table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Following is the table I want to copy from sheet to Doc
[image]

and following I am getting from the code
[image]

I am getting the values only from sheet please see below output

**Sample Data,,,,FirstName,LastName,EmailId,PhoneNo,James,Can,can.james@xxx.xxx,11-xx-xx-xx,Rob,Sen,Sen.rob@XXX.XXX,32-ZZ-ZZ-ZZ**

Comment: Can you share some example screenshots of the typical Sheets format of the copied range?

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: I am able to copy the table data, but how can I copy the format of table also.

Comment: Attach a screenshot of the copied table that you get from running your code too. It is important to remember that modifying any `Doc` element as Text removes all previous formatting, so you will likely want to use something like [`setAttribute`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#setAttributes(Object)) with a style object you create from analyzing the format of the sheet [`range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

Comment: I have added the screen copied table that I am getting from code. Also, setAttribute is for DocumentApp, but I want to copy format(like color,font-family etc.) from source i.e sheet.

Comment: I am well aware that `setAttribute` comes from the DocumentApp. After all, you want to set the attributes of the table in the document. You will need to construct a style object based on the various attributes of the sheet range object (this needs multiple methods of the range class, all available at the documentation link I gave for range).

Comment: Sorry for late reply. If I print the values I am getting the plain text. Please see my update above. With SetAttribute I can set the sytles, but  how can I get those formatting from sheet.